# null pointer from sheet.drawingPatriarch.getChildren()

Tags: java, excel, image, drawing, apache-poi

i trying to read image i inserted before in the excel sheet along with its position with this code, it work fine on my machine but when i migrate the code to another pc i get null pointer exception in the **sheet.getDrawingPatriarch.getChildren()**,i try to googled the problem but i didnt find a solution, anyone mind to help me? Below is the code:

```
   /* loop the sheet */  
    for (int i = 0; i < sheetNumbers; i++) {  

        sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);  
        /* create map to store id map with picture */
        Map<String, PictureData> sheetIndexPicMap = new HashMap<String, PictureData>();   

        /* determine to use 2003's excel get pic method or 2007++ get picture method */
        if (fileExt.equals("xls")) {  
            if(((HSSFSheet) sheet).getDrawingEscherAggregate() != null)
                sheetIndexPicMap = getSheetPictrues03(i, (HSSFSheet) sheet, (HSSFWorkbook) wb);  
        }  
        /* store the picture and id map into a list */
        sheetList.add(sheetIndexPicMap);  
    }  

    printImg(sheetList);  

}  


public static Map<String, PictureData> getSheetPictrues03(int sheetNum,  
        HSSFSheet sheet, HSSFWorkbook workbook) {  

    Map<String, PictureData> sheetIndexPicMap = new HashMap<String, PictureData>();  
    List<HSSFPictureData> pictures = workbook.getAllPictures(); 
    if (pictures.size() != 0) { 

        for (HSSFShape shape : sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getChildren()) {  
            HSSFClientAnchor anchor = (HSSFClientAnchor) shape.getAnchor();  
            if (shape instanceof HSSFPicture) {  
                HSSFPicture pic = (HSSFPicture) shape;  
                int pictureIndex = pic.getPictureIndex() - 1;  
                HSSFPictureData picData = pictures.get(pictureIndex);  
                HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(anchor.getRow1());
                HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
                String picIndex = "ID"+String.valueOf(cell);  

                sheetIndexPicMap.put(picIndex, picData);  
            }  
        }  
        return sheetIndexPicMap;  
    } else {  
        return null;  
    }  
}  


public static void printImg(List<Map<String, PictureData>> sheetList) throws IOException {  

    for (Map<String, PictureData> map : sheetList) {  
        Object key[] = map.keySet().toArray();  
        for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {  
            /*get picture data*/ 
            PictureData pic = map.get(key[i]);  
            /*get row id where the picture reside*/
            String picName = key[i].toString();  
            /*get file extension of the pictur*/
            String ext = pic.suggestFileExtension();  

            byte[] data = pic.getData();  

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("pic" + picName + "." + ext);  
            out.write(data);  
            out.close();  
        }  
    }  

}
```

Comment: It is possible that `sheet` is null or `sheet.getDrawingPatriarch()` returns null. Introduce null check there.

Comment: Are you sure you have the same Apache POI jars on both machines? And neither of them has extra ones?

Comment: i will try to check that, i think this might be the cause, my machine is running poi version 12 while the other machine is running poi version 7, could this be the cause?

Comment: i have imported the same jar file into the new machine, the sheet.getDrawingPatriarch() still getting null while there is image in my excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved, i copy my whole project instead of java file into the new machine, the code works, i guess the issues will be some unsynchronzie jar file between 2 machine, thanks you  @akhil_mittal and @Gagravarr for giving me advice, thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that either `sheet` is `null` or `sheet.getDrawingPatriarch()` returns `null`. Please write the code as:

```
if (pictures.size() != 0) { 
       if(sheet!=null && sheet.getDrawingPatriarch()!=null && sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getChildren()!=null) {
        for (HSSFShape shape : sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getChildren()) {  
            HSSFClientAnchor anchor = (HSSFClientAnchor) shape.getAnchor();  
            if (shape instanceof HSSFPicture) {  
                HSSFPicture pic = (HSSFPicture) shape;  
                int pictureIndex = pic.getPictureIndex() - 1;  
                HSSFPictureData picData = pictures.get(pictureIndex);  
                HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(anchor.getRow1());
                HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
                String picIndex = "ID"+String.valueOf(cell);  

                sheetIndexPicMap.put(picIndex, picData);  
            }  
         }  
       }
       return sheetIndexPicMap;  
    } else {  
        return null;  
    }
```

Comment: thank you for answering, i added the null checking if statement as you suggested, there were no error shown now  but the problem is i cant read the picture data because the  sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getChildren() return null, do you have any idea why the  sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getChildren() return null? there is picture inserted in my sheet and i could read the image in my machine, when i run this code in another machine, the  sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getChildren()  return null. Thanks in advance

Comment: @SoonEe: You may need to debug why you are getting null.